# Какие нужны знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

1. "Иметь собственное жилье, в которое можно с удовольствием возвращаться после тяжелого рабочего дня, мечта каждого жителя нашей огромной страны." После дня ставится тире или запятая?
2. "Доверенность – не самый лучший вариант" нужно ли тире?
3. "Даже перед тем, как купить квартиру в новом доме, ее нужно осмотреть". После "перед тем как" нужна ли запятая?
4. "Подыскивая для себя квартиру, не следует давать объявления о том, что вы собираетесь купить недвижимость, так как это может привлечь не только аферистов, но и воров." Корректно ли предложение?

Answer (score 1):

1. В первом предложении тире должно быть, поскольку подлежащее выражено инфинитивом, а сказуемое - существительное в именительном падеже (составное именное). Та часть, которая выделена запятыми, является придаточным определительным. Получается: *Иметь собственное жилье, в которое можно с удовольствием возвращаться после тяжелого рабочего дня, - мечта каждого жителя нашей огромной страны.*
2. Между подлежащим и сказуемым на месте пропущенной связки тире обычно не ставится, если перед сказуемым, выраженным существительным, есть отрицание НЕ: *Доверенность не самый лучший вариант.* Однако тире возможно, если вы хотите логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое.
3. По третьему предложению ситуация следующая. Если придаточное предложение соединено с главным при помощи сложного подчинительного союза (а **перед тем как** является именно таким союзом), то запятая ставится один раз: перед союзом, если придаточное предложение следует за главным или находится внутри его, и после всего придаточного предложения, если оно предшествует главному. У Розенталя говорится, что к условиям расчленения сложного союза относится наличие перед союзом усилительных, ограничительных и других частиц (в вашем случае это усилительная частица **даже**). Следовательно, вариант, приведенный вами, правильный: *Даже перед тем, как купить квартиру в новом доме, ее нужно осмотреть.*
4. По четвертому предложению у меня замечаний нет. Оно вполне корректно.